# Calculations of table cells simultaneously while entering data using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add calculations to my table cells. Like "rate" column * "quantity" column should be displayed in price column without pressing a button. I have a seperate button for adding rows. As soon as i press that, I get an error for pric saying "cant get value of null"...Please help!!!

Comment: Please update your question with attempted code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!